# Origin of the minimum speed formula for relativistic jets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics

I am studying superluminal motion in relativistic jets.

I understand that the velocity of an emitting part of the jet $v$ can be related to the transverse velocity $v_t$ via

$$ \frac{v}{c} = \frac{(v_t/c)}{\sin \theta + (v_t/c)\cos \theta}$$

The minimum velocity of the jet occurs when $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d} \theta} = 0$ such that $\theta_\text{min} = \arctan\frac{c}{v_t}$. That is all fine and I understand that.

However it is then stated that

$$ \frac{v_\text{min}}{c} = \sqrt{\frac{(v_t/c)^2}{1+(v_t/c)^2}}$$

**I am struggling to see how this is true**.

I have tried substituting $$\sin \theta_\text{min} = \sin\biggl(\arctan\frac{c}{v_t}\biggr) = \frac{c/v_t}{\sqrt{(c/v_t)^2+1}}$$

and a similar expression for the $\cos$ term but I cannot seem to reproduce the expression. Is there another way to justify the formula?

Comment: When you make the substitutions and simplify, what _do_ you get?